# Hot to remove first and last double quotes in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Just like JavaScript, TypeScript also uses the double quote (") or single quote (') to surround string data.
I'm returning some data from back end which contains some HTML.

```
My API response:  <p>afjhjhfsd</p>
```

and I print this on view in angular 4 like {{response}}.
When I inspect in chrome browser it is showing like:

```
"<p>afjhjhfsd</p>"
```

Due to this reason it is also printing paragraph tag on angular 4 view.
Please help me into this.

Comment: It may be that you end up printing a JSON formatted string. I would make the API return an object and print the value of a property, e.g. `{{ response.content }}`. If not possible, I would try to set the response type to string in the http client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try binding to innerHTML

`<div [innerHTML]="response"></div`>

Comment: @SaurabhSharma you are not getting warnings in the browser console because of that? Also if Matt answer satisfies you, you should mark his answer as correct. Thank you.